# Sufficiently large Euler-Characteristic provides zero first cohomology of coherent sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}$
Let $X$ be a projective curve over $k$, $k$ a field. Let $\F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Is there a bound $b(X,\F) \in \mathbb{Z}$ depending on $X$ and $\F$ such that

> $$\chi_k(\F) > b(X,\F) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dim_k \operatorname{H}^1(X,\F) = 0?$$

Comment: What does depend on $\mathcal{F}$ mean? Surely, you can take $b(X,\mathcal{F})=h^0(\mathcal{F})-1$. I am sure you don't mean this.

Comment: @Mohan You're right, I don't mean that. We can formulate Riemann-Roch as $\chi(\mathcal{F}) = deg(\mathcal{F}) + \chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$ where the degree of $\mathcal{F}$ is defined by this equation. Now I wanna know: When do we obtain $h^0(\mathcal{F}) = deg(\mathcal{F}) + \chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$ in terms of $deg(\mathcal{F})$ but not solely in terms of $h^0(\mathcal{F})$ since otherwise we do a 360.

Comment: Long story short: I want to use this to make exact dimension statements about $\mathcal{F}(X)$ and thus I don't assume to know how $h^0(\mathcal{F})$ behaves. However, I want to express this in dependence of  $\chi(\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: Probably you know this already, but for $F$ a line bundle on a smooth curve say, if $\chi(F)>g-1$ then $h^1(F)=0$ by Riemann-Roch and Serre duality.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thank you, but yes, I know that already. I am looking for such a result in a way more general setting.

Comment: In your first comment, your RR is correct only for line bundles. I would suggest you rewrite the question more precisely.

Comment: @Mohan Well, you may define the degree of any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ to satisfy Riemann-Roch, i.e. $\deg_k(\mathcal{F}) := \chi(\mathcal{F}) - \chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$. Do you have any specific definition of the degree of coherent sheaves in mind?

Comment: This not the usual definition of degree. Degree is defined as $\chi(\mathcal{F})-r\chi(\mathcal{O}$ where $r$ is the rank of the sheaf.